# Sharing ports of a service on GitHub Actions

Tags: docker, github, docker-compose, github-actions

To connect to an instance of the ArcadeDB from my GitHub project I use the following workflow file:

```yaml
name: Java CI with Maven

on:
  push:
    branches: [ $default-branch ]
  pull_request:
    branches: [ $default-branch ]
  workflow_dispatch:

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    container:
      image: maven:3.9.1
    services:
        arcadedb:
            image: gfinger/arcadedb:23.3.1
            ports:
                - 2480:2480
    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v3
    - name: Build with Maven
      run: mvn -B package --file pom.xml
    - name: Verify with Maven
      run: mvn -B verify --file pom.xml
```

The docker container for the database server has a well-defined entry-point:

```
...
ENV JAVA_OPTS="-Darcadedb.server.rootPassword=playwithdata \
-Darcadedb.server.plugins=Redis:com.arcadedb.redis.RedisProtocolPlugin,MongoDB:com.arcadedb.mongo.MongoDBProtocolPlugin,Postgres:com.arcadedb.postgres.PostgresProtocolPlugin,GremlinServer:com.arcadedb.server.gremlin.GremlinServerPlugin "
ENTRYPOINT ["./bin/server.sh"]
```

But my project cannot connect to the database. The error message is: "Connection refused: localhost/127.0.0.1:2480".

In a similar docker compose file everything goes well. The docker compose file is:

```
version: '3.8'
services:
  devcontainer:
    image: maven:3.9.1
    volumes:
      - ../..:/workspaces:cached
    network_mode: service:db
    command: sleep infinity

  db:
    image: gfinger/arcadedb:23.3.1
    restart: unless-stopped
```

The referenced docker image for the database service is the same in both cases. But whereas in the compose case my java tests connect without problems to the db, they cannot in case of the GitHub workflow. Does anybody have an idea what is wrong with the definition of the workflow?
The sources are all available on https://github.com/gfinger/arcadeclient

Answer (score 1):

The hostname of the service container is the label of the service, in my case "arcadedb". All service ports are exposed not under "localhost" but under the derived hostname. So in my case, the url to connect to is not: "http://localhost:2480", but "http://arcadedb:2480".

Also: the ports to be exposed from a service container, do not have to be explicitly declared. All opened ports are automatically made visible to the devcontainer, if the workflow uses a devcontainer and is not run directly on the os.